# Python Arduino: not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python-3.x, arduino

I want to use an Arduino to send a message to my phone.

I'm using Twilio's API, Python and Arduino IDE. So i use two push button, if I push button1 the message is " TURN ON LAMP ", and if I push button2 the message is "TURN OFF LAMP".

But there is problem in python:

`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I have hidden my account SID, token and number in the code below.

Arduino Code

```
const int buttonPin1 = 6;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

const int buttonPin2 = 7;

int buttonstate1 = 0;

int buttonstate2 = 0;

void setup() {

 Serial.begin(9600);

 pinMode(buttonPin1, INPUT);

 pinMode(buttonPin2, INPUT);

 pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  buttonstate1 = digitalRead(buttonPin1);

  buttonstate2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2);

  if (buttonstate1 == HIGH) {

    Serial.println("a");

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

    delay(1000);
 } else {
    // turn LED off:

digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

}
  if (buttonstate2 == HIGH) {

    Serial.println("b");

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

    delay(1000);
  }
else {

    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);

  }
```

Python Code

```
import time

import serial

from twilio.rest import Client

arduinoserial = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

time.sleep(2)

account_sid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

auth_token  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

while True:

        if arduinoserial.read('a'):

            print(arduinoserial.readline().str())

            messageTosend="TURN ON LAMP"

            message = client.messages.create(

                                body=messageTosend,

                                from_='+14xxxxxxx',

                                to='+14xxxxxxxx'
                        )
        if arduinoserial.read(int('b')):

            print(arduinoserial.readline().str())

            messageTosend = "TURN OFF LAMP"

            message = client.messages.create(

                body=messageTosend,

                from_='+14xxxxxxxxxxxx',

                to='+14xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            )

time.sleep(1)

print(message.sid)

arduinoserial.close()
```

Comment: please format correctly your code

Answer (score 0):

Your two if statements are the problem.

Here is how serial.read() works:

```
arduinoserial.read() #reads one byte from buffer
arduinoserial.read(10) #reads ten bytes from buffer

arduinoserial.read('a') #makes no sense
```

So here is how you need to adjust your code: (if you want to do this only once get rid of the while loop)

```
while true:
    arduino_input = arduinoserial.readline() #reads a full line of text (also waits till the arduino sent a line of text)

    if arduino_input == 'a': #compares text to 'a'
        [do your stuff here]

    if arduino_input == 'b': #compares text to 'b'
        [do your stuff here]
```

This line of code reads one line from the buffer, converts it to a string and then compares it to another character ('a' or 'b'). If the string and the character is eqivalent the body of the if statement is executed.

Hope this helps. :]